# Select from where plus unconditional select at the same time

Tags: c#, mysql, datagridview

`SELECT Stockid FROM buy WHERE Dividend >0 ORDER by Stockid` works fine in my `datagridview`. Only records shown are those where the Dividend for the particular `Stockid` is greater than 0.

Likewise `SELECT Stockid, Price, Number_Bought, Dividend, Date from buy ORDER by Stockid` also works fine in my `datagridview`. However, records with dividend less than 0 also appear, which is not what I want.

Is there a way to combine the two queries together so that if there is no Dividend for a particular Stockid, that row will not appear in the datagridview?
("buy" is the table).

Hope someone can help me with this conundrum.

Comment: `is not null` might be what you're looking for - otherwise, please post example data

Comment: try using where in second query..tried?

Comment: Read the question, you 'll get the answer... ;)

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to simply include the same WHERE clause in the second query:

```
SELECT Stockid, Price, Number_Bought, Dividend, Date 
FROM buy 
WHERE Dividend > 0
ORDER by Stockid
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do like this way :

```
SELECT Stockid, Price, Number_Bought, Dividend, Date 
FROM buy 
WHERE Dividend <> 0 
ORDER by Stockid
```

Comment: Many thanks for the information.  I found that I could not keep the information in just one table after all,  because depending on what information I wanted to record I had a problem with not allowing nulls for other fields.  I have gone to two tables one for buy transactions and one for income transactions  and this works well EXCEPT now I cannot get correct information from the two tables into the one datagridview.  Accordingly, I have posted a new question.

Comment: @Johnkg, if any answer is helpful for you to resolve your problem please upvote or accept it. It will be helpful others too. thanks